# How to retain a form's checkbox values while using a pager

Tags: 7, forms

I am generating a checklist form after a database query. In the database query I am using `->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(50)`, and when I render the form, I use `.theme('pager')`.

But after selecting certain items (checkboxes) on page 1 and then when I navigate to page 2 and make some selections, and then when I navigate back to page 1, my selections on page 2 as well as page 1 that I had previously made are lost.

Please suggest any means to retain the checklist selections.

Comment: Drupal doesn't have any functionality like that (nor does any other CMS/Framework I've used before); it isn't a trivial thing to set up. VBO has a feature that allows you to select the remaining options from subsequent pages, but nothing like what you're looking for. The real question is this: What method would you use to do the same thing in a basic PHP site, _outside_ of Drupal? Once you've got that worked out, implementing inside Drupal should be fairly straightforward

Comment: @clive I am looking for solution for the the same question for one my project, how about appending the checked checboxes keys into browser cookies and with jqeury we can read checked checkboxes from keys and set them as checked and once the form is submitted the cookie value can be set to null,I am not sure if this help out in any way,please add your suggestions if this approch can be improvised or if does not serve the solution.